# What's the Idiomatic Cypher way to traverse linked nodes?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Given the following structure

```
(:Path)-[:STARTS_AT]->(:Location)
(:Path)-[:ENDS_AT]->(:Location) 
(:Location)-[:NEXT_STOP]->(:Location)
```

How would I find a location between two stops that matches a specific condition?
For instance if I want to know if the name of a location is between A or B (with A ≠ B). I've come up with the following query:

```
WITH $startNode AS startNode, $endNode AS endNode

MATCH (startNode) -[a:NEXT_STOP*0..]->(location:Location{name: 'My location'}) -[b:NEXT_STOP*0..]-> (endNode)
WHERE (a IS NOT NULL OR b IS NOT NULL)
RETURN location
```

Because the location might be the startNode or endNode, I need to evaluate that at least one NEXT_STOP relation exists.
Is there a way to avoid these null-checks but still include the edges of the path?

Answer (score 1):

I would say this is the most Cypher-like additional filter to pathfinding

```
WITH $startNode AS startNode, $endNode AS endNode

MATCH p=(startNode) -[a:NEXT_STOP*]->(endNode)
WHERE any(n in nodes(p) WHERE n.name = 'My location')
RETURN location
```

To skip null-checks, all you have to do is to remove `0` from rel descriptions:

```
WITH $startNode AS startNode, $endNode AS endNode

MATCH (startNode) -[a:NEXT_STOP*]->(location:Location{name: 'My location'}) -[b:NEXT_STOP*]-> (endNode)
WHERE (a IS NOT NULL OR b IS NOT NULL)
RETURN location
```

Comment: I like the suggestion, but unfortunately, I'd have to add more stuff to get to the matching location. As for removing the minimum length of 0, that would exclude the edges of the chain. 
_Omitting both bounds is equivalent to specifying a minimum of 1_

Comment: Yes, minimum of 1 allows to skip null checks?

Comment: But if startNode or endNode is the location you're looking for, you will not get a match. You'll only match those nodes that are at least one away from both startNode and endNode.